# How can I get SubMenu in xml?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_first"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_second"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_third"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true">

        <menu 
            android:id="@+id/menu_revice" >

            <item
                android:id="@+id/ap_none"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Item in SubMenu 1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ap_mid"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="Item in SubMenu 2"/>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

this is my menu.xml file. 
I need to get SubMenu 'menu_revice', in 'item_thrid'.
then i tried that in onCreate(), onCreateOptionsMenu(), onOptionsItemSelected(),  onPrepareOptionsMenu():

```
Menu MainMenu

//try 1
Menu subMenu = (Menu)findViewById(R.id.menu_revice); // nullPointerException

// try 2
SubMenu subMenu = (SubMenu)findViewById(R.id.menu_revice); // nullPointerException
```

Why nullpointerException is occured..?
I don't know how can I get SubMenu.
Please tell me how...
Thanks.

Comment: Menu items are not 'views' therefore you can't use `findViewById(...)`. Why are you trying to do this anyway? When a menu item is selected, the relevant `MenuItem` is passed to the handler and you can then get its id from that and act accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` :

```
menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu(); //submenu for item in position 0
```

**EDIT:**

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getSubMenu()

Comment: Please add a link to the API documentation to make the answer complete.

Comment: Thank You! I solved problem. From now on, I will check API document first.